# Spring Controller + Ajax return String

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller, controller

I want to return String from `Spring MVC Controller` to `Ajax`.
It is not working as expected and gives error.

My Ajax codes for this:

```
function ajaxRequest(item) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myPage",
        data: {
           item: item
        },
        success: function (html) {

            alert(html);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log("Error:" + e);
        }
    });

}
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myPage", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces="text/plain")
public @ResponseBody String myController(HttpServletRequest request) {
String myItem = request.getParameter("item");   

...

return myItem + "bla bla bla";
}
```

Chrome console result:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/myPage 406 (Not Acceptable) jquery.js
Error:[object XMLHttpRequest]
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 5):

When you return a `String` from a handler method annotated with `@ResponseBody`, Spring will use a `StringHttpMessageConverter` which sets the return content-type to `text/plain`. However, your request does not have an `Accept` header for that content-type so the Server (your Spring app) deems it unacceptable to return `text/plain`.

Change your ajax to add the `Accept` header for `text/plain`.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it. We can return correct values with response writer.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/myPage")
    public void myController(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String myItem = request.getParameter("item");   

    ...

    response.getWriter().println(myItem + "bla bla bla");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Be sure that you have Jackson dependency. Spring MVC can relies on it.

Comment: Jackson is not involved here.